# Haskell Error: error: [-Wunused-matches, -Werror=unused-matches] Defined but not used: `xs'

Tags: haskell

I get this kind of Error:

```
error: [-Wunused-matches, -Werror=unused-matches]
Defined but not used: `xs'
```

My code is

```
gameToString :: Game -> String
gameToString ((x):(y):(z):(xs)) = (rowToString x) ++ (rowToString y) ++ (rowToString z)
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

In a function definition, if you pattern match on a variable on the left-hand side that doesn't appear on the right-hand side:

```
gameToString (x:y:z:xs) = ... no "xs" in here ...
                    ^^
                     `-- "xs" appears here
```

this is legal Haskell code, but it *might* indicate a programming error.  So, there is a compiler flag `-Wunused-matches` that generates a compilation warning if this happens.  If you specify `-Wall`, this turns on lots of warnings, including this one.

Normally, compilation will still be successful, but if you also specify the compiler flag `-Werror`, this turns all warnings into compilation errors.

So, you are compiling legal Haskell code but probably with the compiler flags `-Wall -Werror`, which generates a warning that gets upgraded to an error.

To fix this, you need to indicate to Haskell that `xs` is unused on purpose.  You can do this by using the `_` wildcard in place of `xs`:

```
gameToString (x:y:z:_) = ...
```

or by using a name that starts with an underscore:

```
gameToString (x:y:z:_xs) = ...
```

Both will suppress this warning.

If `-Wall` is turned on (or if `-Wincomplete-patterns` is turned on), you'll have another fatal warning, because your definition of `gameToString` only matches lists of length three or more.  This will result in a `Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive` warning/error.  To avoid this, you'll need to add another case to handle invalid games:

```
gameToString :: Game -> String
gameToString (x:y:z:_) = rowToString x ++ rowToString y ++ rowToString z
gameToString _ = error "internal error: invalid Game"
```

Comment: Alternatively, fix the bug by actually using `xs`. Seems like it'd be pretty weird for `gameToString` to expect a `Game` to have *at least* three rows, but not care what the rows beyond the third are.

Comment: @amalloy I'd guess it's a tic-tac-toe game, and exactly 3 strings are expected. I'd use `[x,y,z]` then, or even `(x,y,z)` or a custom data type, since using lists seems a bit weird.

Comment: @chi Sure. In that case exactly three rows are expected, so the compiler error is correctly pointing out that the pattern doesn't match what the programmer intended. Just throwing an underscore in there to shut it up is not getting value out of it.